# html button to display php script results

Tags: php, html

I have this script in a separate file as my index.php.

I want to have a button that if pressed shows the results from my PHP script in the index.php, but when I use

```
<form action="../inc/script.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Scan">
</form>
```

it just goes to the script.php page. how can I change it so it stays on index.php and print_r the array from the script on the index.php page?

Comment: Read about AJAX

Comment: the word is `method` and not `methode`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Not everybody speaks English as a first language.

Comment: @IMSoP I know, but syntax is English-based, *n'est-ce pas?*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Ah, I see your point; your comment still seems blunt though, since it's not actually the answer to the question (which is the classic confusion over server vs client code). It could have been something like "By the way, you have a mistake in your HTML, it should be `method=` not `methode=`"

Comment: @IMSoP I question the edit though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form action tells the browser to post the form results to that page. If you want to stay on the current page you'll need to remove the action. Then, you'll have to check the post and include the results within the current page.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="Scan" value="Scan">
</form>

<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['Scan'])) { 
        include '../inc/script.php';
    } 
?>
```

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly 

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is through using JavaScript, and specifically `jQuery` in my example.

What you would do is set up a `POST` request to the PHP document, that would return the `print_r` result. You also won't need a form in this instance, more than a button.

HTML:

`<button type="button" id="scan"></button>`

AND

`<div id="returned-data"></div>`

so you  have a place to put the data when you get it back.

JS/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#scan').click(function(){
        $.post('../inc/script.php').done(function(data){
            $('#returned-data').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

PHP (../inc/script.php):

```
<?php
    //do something with your data, and finish with:
    print_r($data);
?>
```